# C# Color coding for windows 8.1 (tablet) in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, windows-8.1

May I know how should I write the **color** code for

> grid-background / textblock-foreground

```
if(Condition ==true)
{
   gridName.Backgroud = //How to set color here
}
```

in **visual studio 2013**? (For Windows 8.1 tablet (surfaceRT) )

Comment: Can you describe your task detailed?

Comment: @ad1Dima I am suppose to change the set a color(red) , If(something = true) the grid/textblock should change to green.

Comment: What have you tried? Give us some more information of what you are trying to achieve!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try these options

```
if(Contition == true)
{
    // you can try this
    grid.Background = new SolidColorBurush(Colors.Green);

    // you can try this too
    grid.Background =  new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 255, 0);    
}
```

If you having Error that Colors or Color does not exists or you are missing some assembly.
so just right Click on Colors/Color and choose Resolve Option. it is all done :)

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

For ex

```
if(something == true)
{
   grid.Background = new SolidColorBurush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red);
}
```

Comment: colors is not found in vs2013

Comment: @Hathaway add namespase Windows.UI to usings. Or you can add Windows.UI.Colors